# Change building to Xcode beta

Tags: xcode, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

Is possible to change between building by Xcode 10 and Xcode 11 beta?
Maybe by editing by config file etc.?

I have installed both and I need to switch between them.
 
Is it possible?

Comment: xcode-select? That's what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swtich between multiple versions of Xcode, `xcode-select` should do the job.

Print current version path

```
xcode-select -p
```

To switch

```
xcode-select -s path-to-different-version
```